# SonarQube pdf report creation

Tags: java, maven, pdf, sonarqube, sonarqube5.3

I have been using SonarQube(5.3) for a while but recently I decided to get a pdf report. I just installed a pdf plugin.(I believe there is only one plugin for this). But I cannot find the pdf anywhere. I already checked out answers. They say I can add by customizing the widget but It is not there either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PDF Report plugin [isn't compatible past v4.5](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Version+Matrix). The commercial [Report Plugin](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/governance/report/) will let you email PDF's, however.

Comment: Oh my... that plugin uses an *ancient* version of iText to create PDF files: 2.1.4. A version with known legal and technical issues. Meanwhile we at iText (the company) use SonarQube to check the quality of iText (the software). Is that plugin still under development? If I ever feel bored, I might pick it up as a side project and make it compatible with current versions of SonarQube and iText. No promises, though!

Comment: To be clear, my comment was about the *PDF Report Plugin*. The commercial *Report Plugin* uses `Qt 4.8.0 (C) 2011 Nokia Corporation and/or its subsidiary(-ies)` for PDF creation.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It looks like I installed the pdf plugin from sonarsource.com. But it is asking for license key. Not sure where to enter?(I already requested for a trial key)  or how can I use the community edition?

Comment: You have to wait for the response with the trial key